# Why Python allows def functions inside for loop

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new at Python, but I tried something and it was ambiguous for me.
Why Python allows doing def of function inside a loop ? and how I can benefit from that ?

```
for i in range(2):
  def f():
     print 'f'

  f()
```

Comment: It's a side effect of Python allowing def anywhere. You could store the function definitions in an array if you like.

Answer (score 3):

Well because python is a high level programming language, you can actually return functions. The following a simple yet demonstrative function.

```
def multiplier(multiple):
  def f(number):
    return multiple * number
  return f
```

you can use that function as follows:

```
double = multiplier(2)
print double(3)
```

which would print 6.

Same concept would apply for loops if you want to make multiple functions for example and store them in a list or any other purpose befitting your needs.

```
list_of_functions = [] #list of functions
for i in range(2):
  def f(n):
    def printer():
      print "f"*n
    return printer
  list_of_functions.append(f(i+1))
```

Now you can call list_of_functions`[0`]() which would print 'f' and list_of_functions`[1`]() which would print 'ff'.

Comment: What are those `end`s doing there, besides causing `NameError`? Also, [please don't use `l` as a variable name](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions)...

Comment: @HenryKeiter thank you for noticing what do you suggest instead of l, I just used it to represent a list

Comment: The problem with l is that it looks a lot like 1 or I. How about 'lof' for "list of functions"?

Comment: How about `list_of_functions` for "list of functions"? _Readability counts._

Answer (score 2):

You can define functions anywhere! Because Python is dynamic in this way, you can create functions (and classes, and pretty much anything else) at runtime. It's difficult to come up with a simple example of why you'd want to do this without it seeming contrived, but use cases certainly do exist.

Let's say you're writing a simple processing framework. You'll allow users to type commands, which will cause certain functions to run. You can define those functions first, and then store them all in a dictionary, so that you can quickly look up the appropriate function to run when you get the user's input.

```
def define_functions(letters):
    commands = {} # dictionary of commands
    for letter in letters:
        # Define functions dynamically
        if letter == 'f':
            def _function():
                print('foo')
        elif letter == 'b':
            def _function():
                print('bar')
        elif letter == 'z':
            def _function():
                print('baz')
        else:
            def _function():
                print('Unknown command')

        # Add the new function to the dictionary with the key "n squared"
        commands[letter] = _function
    return commands

commands = define_functions('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

# Now we have a dictionary of functions.

while True: # loop forever
    # Ask for input and run the specified function!
    func_name = raw_input('Enter the one-letter name of the function to run: ')
    if func_name not in commands:
        print("sorry, that function isn't defined.")
        break

    # Look up the function
    func = commands.get(func_name)

    # Call the function
    func()
```